# What happens with ggplot (geom_smooth(method = "loess) when span > 1?

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing, loess

Imagine a `ggplot` that uses `geom_smooth(method = "loess", span = 1.5)`. In that ggplot, what is the span argument telling ggplot to do to the `geom_smooth` lines (or the associated math)?

I have read the previous discussions on the function of the `span` argument (and the related discussion of `alpha`), but they have discussed it as being bounded by 0 and 1. This is not true, and `span = 1.5` (for example) creates a different smoothness than `span = 1`.

Comment: This is a good question and you will likely get better, faster help if you include reproducible examples. Instead of inviting folks to imagine what it would be, just demonstrate with code exactly what you are asking. Good luck!

Comment: Some specificity would help here. It's hard to imagine what hypothetical code does and harder still to imagine what would happen if I changed a parameter, and you're referring to discussions that aren't included in the question. Why not make an example where you try changing the argument to show what exactly you're asking about and why the value would or wouldn't be bounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loess smoothing method uses `stats::loess`, and the help for that function gives more context about how the span parameter works when it's greater than one.

`?loess`

> span
> the parameter α which controls the degree of smoothing.

> Details
> Fitting is done locally. That is, for the fit at point x, the
> fit is made using points in a neighbourhood of xx, weighted by their
> distance from xx (with differences in ‘parametric’ variables being
> ignored when computing the distance). The size of the neighbourhood is
> controlled by α (set by span or enp.target). For α<1,
> the neighbourhood includes proportion α of the points, and these
> have tricubic weighting (proportional to (1 -
> (dist/maxdist)^3)^3). For
> α>1, all points are used, with the ‘maximum distance’ assumed to be α ^ (1/p)   times the actual maximum distance for p
> explanatory variables.

In other words, when span is > 1 all the points are included, and the larger it gets, the less "local" the weighting gets.